# I want to avoid errors in my function php

Tags: php

how can I avoid errors in my function for example

```
function subtract($a,$b) {return $a-$b ;}
```

I want the function to return message instead of error for instance

```
echo subtract("string",5) ; // output fatal error
```

instead I want it to return message (I don't want to use if condition )

Comment: Would this make the processing of the function more complex - you will either get a number back or a string with some form of message.  This just moves the processing down the chain rather than dealing with it in the first instance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63140368/php-how-do-i-set-different-types-of-throw-errors

Comment: if you are on php 8 and wanted an exception (that you can catch later), you can use [type hinting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php). it cost some cycles, but make sure whoever uses the function wont do unwanted stuff.

Comment: @BagusTesa You only need PHP 7 for those (and literally everyone should be using 7.x by now), but they'll just give the error *earlier* rather than changing it into a message. (Also, technically, they're not just "hints", which is why the manual calls them type *declarations*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just catch the fatal error with a try-catch block.

```
function subtract($a,$b)
{
    try
    {
        return $a-$b ;
    }
    catch(Throwable $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```