# Declaring a variable as a string and later using it as an array?

Tags: php, php-7.4

Did something change in the PHP where declaring a variable as a string and later using it as an array is not OK. We upgraded to bitnamies wamp stack and it broke our app. One of the variables

`$change="";`

Then later used

`$change[$k] = "this";`

It remains a single string instead of turning into an array. Is this a php.ini config I can change?

Comment: There's no such config. Either declare variable as array or do not perform such type conversions.

Comment: Yes there were changes. As of 7.1 Now that would end up as `string(1) "t"`? [**Assignment via string index access on an empty string**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php#migration71.incompatible.empty-string-modifcation-by-character)

Comment: You could compare old versions behavior with https://3v4l.org/84hl3 And yes, they did change behavior in PHP 7

Comment: That makes sense because that was my result I guess I am just going to have to poke other variables and fix them as well

Answer (score 4):

As of 7.1 the behavior you describe changed. See change log for [**Assignment via string index access on an empty string**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php#migration71.incompatible.empty-string-modifcation-by-character)

> String modification by character on an empty string now works like for
> non-empty strings, i.e. writing to an out of range offset pads the
> string with spaces, where non-integer types are converted to integer,
> and only the first character of the assigned string is used. Formerly,
> empty strings where silently treated like an empty array.

```
<?php
$change='';
$change[2] = "this";
var_dump($change); 

/*
Prior to 7.1: 
  array(1) {
    [2]=>
    string(4) "this"
  }

7.1 and up:
  string(3) "  t"
```

PHP 7 has seen numerous improvements that make "stricter" typing possible and allow for better [type hinting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration). PHP is still considered a loosely typed language though. Some examples include, as of 7.0, [Scalar type declarations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.scalar-type-declarations), [Return type declarations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations) and the [`strict_types`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723637/what-do-strict-types-do-in-php) directive.