# Do we still need 'declare(strict_types=1)' in PHP 8.1?

Tags: php

As asked above, are we still required to put `declare(strict_types=1)` in the header of every single program in our projects in PHP 8.1?

I'd love for it to be just strict all the time.

Comment: PHP 8.1 does not have strict types always on, you still need the declaration if you want it.

Comment: Nikita Popov made a proposal in 2016 ([PHP RFC: Namespace-scoped declares](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/namespace_scoped_declares)) but I think it didn't get past the discussion phase.

Comment: Well, here is hoping it comes soon.

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes! Tested with PHP 8.1.7 there is still a difference.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723637/what-do-strict-types-do-in-php) to understand what the strict types do.

New in PHP 8.1: when a float value is coerced to an int value implicitly, like in the example from the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723637/what-do-strict-types-do-in-php), a deprecation notice is triggered:
`PHP Deprecated:  Implicit conversion from float 1.4 to int loses precision`. [More details](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/deprecate-implicit-conversion-incompatible-float-string#:%7E:text=From%20PHP%208.1%2C%20a%20deprecation,Strict%20Types%20has%20not%20changed.)

**Further reading**

- [What do strict types do in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723637/what-do-strict-types-do-in-php)
- [PHP 8.1: Implicit incompatible float to int conversion is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723637/what-do-strict-types-do-in-php)