# declare(strict_types=1) globally in PHP 8.2

Tags: php, php-8.2, laravel-10

With all the new upgrades released in `PHP 8.2` with readonly classes, is it possible to do:

```
declare(strict_types=1);
```

globally in a project?

Comment: @dev_mustafa with all due respect, `php 7` (2015 released) != `php 8.2` (2022 released)

Comment: Although some of the concepts may be different, the main substance of the link from @dev_mustafa may still be correct.  Will have to see if there is any further input.

Comment: @NigelRen I would hope so, especially since PHP has been consistently releasing new changes thought the years to the type system and type casting, it would seems as if they will eventually make it a requirement, especially since major Frameworks & IDEs are incorporating it now. I would personally love to hear if anyone has discovered a way to make it globally enforced.

Comment: Not good - but also just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71097200/do-we-still-need-declarestrict-types-1-in-php-8-1

Comment: To define that globally, it would possible be needed to resolve this before being able to do so: [Function calls from within internal functions will not be affected by the strict_types declaration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.strict:~:text=Function%20calls%20from%20within%20internal%20functions%20will%20not%20be%20affected%20by%20the%20strict_types%20declaration)  ?